# PostgreSQL query issues

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB with multiple tables which also have multiple rows/columns with a layout similar to that shown below.

the site is in a table named sites and ID and Type are in a table labelled Site_EQ

```
Site  ID Type  
A0004  2 abc
A0004  3 abcd
A0004  4 abcde
A0005  2 abc
A0005  3 abcd
A0005  4 abcde 
A0005  5 abc  
A0005  6 abcd 
A0005  7 abcde
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is filter the results by site finding the highest ID value per site and removing the others, so if for example A0010 had ID's 1-20 I would like the result to show.

```
A0010 20 Bla
```

and ignore the

```
A0010 1 Bla
A0010 2 Bla
```

and so on, but am not sure how to go about doing so as there is no set number of ID it could be 1-3 or 1-30, essentially giving me 30 results for a single site with only 1 column different (which I would like to filter to the highest value only).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select Site, ID, Type from
(select s.*, row_number() over (partition by Site order by ID desc) rn
 from Site_EQ) q
where rn=1
```

Comment: Apologies I can do the entire query from one table... I have added unnecessary info into the query I feel soo stupid.

SELECT site, max(ID)+1 as ID
FROM site_eq
GROUP BY site
ORDER BY max(ID)+1 DESC
LIMIT x;

did the job fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT T1.Site, T1.ID, T1.Type
FROM SomeTable T1, (SELECT Site, MAX(ID) AS ID
                    FROM SomeTable
                    GROUP BY Site) T2
WHERE T2.Site = T1.Site
AND T2.ID = T1.ID
```

The trick is have a sub query that gives you the Site + maximum ID, you can't retrieve the Type at the same time though due to the grouping so you need to join it again with the actual table.

Here you can find the explanation on Table Alias (`T1` and `T2`):
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES

Comment: Please don't link to outdated versions of the manual, use "current" instead of the "8.2" (unless the user asking the question specifically states a version)

Comment: sure thing, I'm not a Postgre man, just linked to the first one I found via Google, also the alias thing is unlikely to have changed in later versions, updated the link to the current version now

Comment: Thanks. I actually meant to use the word *current* instead of the version number though ;)

Comment: Ah ok, sure thing, didn't know that work, not a Postgree guy as I said:) Also how do we know they do not change the structure of the next doc and the link goes into nowhere land?